# Error in sending data from Zendesk to External API using Trigger

Tags: java, spring-boot, webhooks, zendesk, zendesk-api

I have been using Zendesk to create tickets for user queries and I need to have the ticket status tracking in my own server.

I have integrated Zendesk Trigger for the same but i am not getting any callbacks from Zendesk.

I configured to get ticket id from Zendesk callback.

Upon checking the API tab in Zendesk support, the **Status** is '-' and the **Failure Type** is mentioned as 'execution expired'.

On the Detail view of the API tab, I am getting the following data

**Ticket Creation**

*Request*
There are no request details for this failure.

*Response*
There are no response details for this failure.

Server side code is done using spring boot.

```
  @GetMapping("/zenDeskTicketCreation")
    public ResponseModel zenDeskTicketCreation(@RequestParam int ticketId) {
        ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
        System.out.println("Response from Zendesk Trigger ===========> " + ticketId);
        responseModel.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS);
        return responseModel;
    }
```

URL given to zendesk to send the data

```
http://myDomain:8080/v1/admin/zenDeskTicketCreation?ticketId={{ticket.id}}
```

I am attaching my Zendesk screenshots for your reference

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any headsup on this would be really helpful!